# Why are there keywords and standard stereotypes?

Tags: uml

Some times I use keywords like `<<use>>` and some times standard stereotypes like `<<Create>>` .

But I wonder why the two notions exist in UML. I feel that keywords could be integrated in a profile.

So does someone knonw why there is a set of keywords AND standard stereotypes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visually there is no way to distinguish a keyword from a stereotype.

Keywords are a notation feature.
They are used when there is no other notation available or as an alternative notation. This alternative notation is usually a simple rectangle with the name of the meta-type as keyword.

Keywords are used only for **existing** meta-classes from the UML meta-model. So in the case of «use» you are actually modelling a `Usage` relation for which the notation is the same as a Dependency with the addition of the «use» keyword.

Stereotypes on the other hand are an **extension** of the UML meta-model. By defining a stereotype in a profile you are inventing your own meta-classes who extend existing UML meta-classs. The notation for such an extended meta-class is to show the notation for the standard UML metaclass + the name of the stereotype between guillemets («stereotype»)

The *standard* stereotypes you are referring to are defined in the *UML Standard Profile* (see specs 2.5 at page 677).

> The Standard Profile specifies a set of predefined standard stereotypes. A conforming tool shall support all of the
>   stereotypes in the Standard Profile.

The example «Create» is defined in this Standard profile as an extension of the Usage meta-class.
[image]

The reason why some concepts are real meta-classes (such as `Usage`) and others are extended metatypes (stereotypes) defined in the standard profile (such as `Create`) is not immediately clear. I personally suspect that this whole *Standard Profile* is the result of a compromise between the different parties in the committee that had to define the UML specs.
By defining it in the Standard Profile instead of as a proper meta-class it is not really in the specs, but also not really out either.

Comment: Indeed, but the question is why the both ? It could be possible to define a stereotype `Use` no ?

Comment: This is a flaw in the UML specs (or I'd call it that way). Using the same rendering for different concepts is never a good idea. Likely it has historic roots and they don't dare to change it :-/

Comment: It would, but changing the specs would require a lot of effort for both changing the specs, UML-compliant tools, and most likely users utilizing profiles. In the end it would be a lot of work with little added value. So maybe 3.0 :-D

Comment: @granier it is possible to define a stereotype  «Use» but that might lead to confusion between this stereotype and the meta-class `Usage`

Comment: @ThomasKilian I'm not convinced it's a flaw. From a users perspective these words between guillemets denote the same thing. The fact that an element is of a certain meta-type. Whether it is a standard meta-type from UML, or an extended meta-type (stereotype) is usually not relevant for a user working in a specific environment.

Comment: See on p. 743: _Not all words appearing between guillemets are necessarily keywords, and words appearing in guillemets do not necessarily represent stereotypes._ Nice note. Ambiguation per default.

Comment: @Peter maybe provide the more meaning full remark no ?

Comment: @Peter, if you create an anwser with your comment i will mark the question as anwsered.

Comment: @granier it was just an addendum to Geert 's answer (and he's free to append it to his answer). I merely stated why it would be hard to change. Geert actually answered your question. :)